# Get Twitter updates using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want twitter updates within 10 seconds of interval of dynamic users.I have written following code but it is taking only query and user name as "microsoft", others name are not accepted. My code is as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
                <!-- DC Twitter CSS -->
        <link href="twitter/jquery.tweet.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- jQuery Library (skip this step if already called on page ) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="twitter/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- (do not call twice) -->

        <!-- DC Twitter JS -->
        <script src="twitter/jquery.tweet.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $(".query").tweet({
                username: "microsoft",
                avatar_size: 16, // avatar size in px
                count: 10, // how many tweets to show
                query: "#microsoft", // search query
                loading_text: "searching twitter...",
                refresh_interval: 10 // seconds before next refresh
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="query" class="query" style="width:80%;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is happening inside.Suggestions are welcomed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does "not accepted" mean?

Comment: put in a jsfiddle. So easy to give answer

Comment: "not accepted" means it is accepting name as microsoft only! Others name are not accepted!It is not showing others twits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username can be blank, you just need to update the query parameter to change the results, this could also be dynamic, what are you trying to do exactly?

eg: for fred it would be:

```
<html>
<head>
            <!-- DC Twitter CSS -->
    <link href="twitter/jquery.tweet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery Library (skip this step if already called on page ) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> <!-- (do not call twice) -->

    <!-- DC Twitter JS -->
    <script src="twitter/jquery.tweet.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".query").tweet({
            username: "",
            avatar_size: 16, // avatar size in px
            count: 10, // how many tweets to show
            query: "fred", // search query
            loading_text: "searching twitter...",
            refresh_interval: 10 // seconds before next refresh
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="query" class="query" style="width:80%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

for hashtag fred (#fred) it would be:

```
<html>
<head>
            <!-- DC Twitter CSS -->
    <link href="twitter/jquery.tweet.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- jQuery Library (skip this step if already called on page ) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script> <!-- (do not call twice) -->

    <!-- DC Twitter JS -->
    <script src="twitter/jquery.tweet.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".query").tweet({
            username: "",
            avatar_size: 16, // avatar size in px
            count: 10, // how many tweets to show
            query: "#fred", // search query
            loading_text: "searching twitter...",
            refresh_interval: 10 // seconds before next refresh
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="query" class="query" style="width:80%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MNebj/

Comment: Yes i have already tried this.What is #fred here? Is it your user name?My username is JariwalaKomal so i have tried, query: "#jariwalakomal" but it is not showing any twits for that only page loading within 10 seconds!

Comment: If you just want tweets from a user then just add the username and no query...http://jsfiddle.net/f5eUe/1/

Comment: The query parameter is for tweets that contain that word and the username is for tweets from a user. So if you want all tweets and retweets to you, you would put 'jariwalakomal' in the query...

Comment: thanks..Liam Baldwin n only username is not working and giving me an error as "bad request"!Sorry i have to give username with query="".So that it is working otherwise not. Thanks..

Comment: Thats exactly what is here: http://jsfiddle.net/f5eUe/1/ just put username: "jariwalakomal" and query: "" - username: "@jariwalakomal" works too.